# ItemsControl not wrapping items onto next line

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following CntrolTemplate that has a HierarchicalDataTemplate that displays a custom DataType I have.  Its simply an ItemsControl with a stackPanel that displays a button and some text.

The problem I am having is that the content does not wrap around and go to the next line when lots of items are added:

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyControlTemplate">
    <StackPanel x:Name="MyStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto" Margin="0,1,0,1" Background="{x:Null}">
        <ItemsControl  x:Name="MyItemsControl" Margin="5,0,5,0" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyClass}}, Path=ItemsSource}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True">
                        <StackPanel.Resources>
                            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibility"/>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyCustomDataType}">
                                <Button Height="24" MinWidth="16" Width="Auto" Command="{Binding}" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"                                           
                                        Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                        <Image Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding Path=IconSource}" 
                                               Visibility="{Binding Path=HideInTileGroup, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto"
                                                   Foreground="{Binding Path=DisplayBrush}"
                                                   Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowDisplayName, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" FontSize="12">
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Button>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        </StackPanel.Resources>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

How can I make it wrap around?

**EDIT:**

I have changed it to a WrapPanel like so but still it doesn't wrap.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyControlTemplate">
<StackPanel x:Name="MyStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto" Margin="0,1,0,1" Background="{x:Null}">
    <ItemsControl  x:Name="MyItemsControl" Margin="5,0,5,0" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyClass}}, Path=ItemsSource}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <WrapPanel.Resources>
                        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibility"/>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyCustomDataType}">
                            <Button Height="24" MinWidth="16" Width="Auto" Command="{Binding}" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"                                           
                                    Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Image Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding Path=IconSource}" 
                                           Visibility="{Binding Path=HideInTileGroup, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto"
                                               Foreground="{Binding Path=DisplayBrush}"
                                               Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowDisplayName, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}" FontSize="12">
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </WrapPanel.Resources>                            
                </WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Use a WrapPanel instead of a StackPanel?

Comment: So my outer StackPanel  is a WrapPanel? ANd keep the inner ItemsControl the same??

Comment: I mean the ItemsPanel.

Comment: See my edit please.  I have changed the StackPanel to WrapPanel but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 3):

If changing the `ItemsPanel` to a `WrapPanel` hasn't worked, it's because you still have an outer `StackPanel`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyControlTemplate">
    <StackPanel x:Name="MyStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto" Margin="0,1,0,1" Background="{x:Null}">
```

This means that the `ItemsPanel` still thinks it has infinite width to deal with so won't actually wrap.

Either remove the outer `StackPanel` completely, replace it with some other container or limit it's width. I see nothing in your code that says to me you need that outer container so I'd simply remove it and go from there.

If it's still not wrapping there still must be another "infinite width" (i.e one that grows to fit it's contents) container somewhere in the visual tree. You;ll need to work outwards from this item until you find it.

Comment: I set the width and height of the outer stack panel to 800 and it doesn't wrap it simply limits the number of images that it can fit in width 800.  I also removed the outer stack panel and it still doesn't wrap.  Do I 'need' to replace it with another container??

Comment: @HarryBoy I'd say you don't need to replace it with another container - at least from the code you've posted. You only need containers if there are going to be several "things" to display. If it's still not wrapping there still must be another "infinite width" (i.e one that grows to fit it's contents) container somewhere in the visual tree.

Answer (score 0):

you can also set the item control panel to specific layout or panel

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

example

```
<Grid Margin="0 20 0 0">


                                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SourceCollection}">
                                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                    <WrapPanel />
                                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                        <materialDesign:Card Width="200" Height="200" Margin="16">
                                                            <TextBlock Text="XX" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                        </materialDesign:Card>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                   

                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>


                                        </ItemsControl>


                                </Grid>
```